# Подскажите, пожалуйста, что происходит в этом коде?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Знаю, что здесь такие вопросы не особо любят, но подскажите, пожалуйста. Я встретил одну реализацию таймера, где увидел вот такое чудо. В шаблонах не силён, но здесь не понял ВООБЩЕ ничего:

```
template <class callable, class... arguments>
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<callable>::value>::type setTimer(const std::string &tag,float delay, callable&& f, arguments&&... args)
        {
            std::function<void()> task(std::bind(callable(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));
            Timers.emplace_back(std::make_shared<CTimer>(std::move(task),tag,delay));
        };
```

Если быть точным, то я не могу понять что происходит в первой строке:
`typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<callable>::value>::type setTimer(const std::string &tag,float delay, callable&& f, arguments&&... args)`, судя по всему это шаблон функции, где тип возвращаемого значения: `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<callable>::value>::type`.

Теперь по порядку:

1. `!std::is_arithmetic<callable>::value` - если тип арифметический , то вернет `true`, но здесь инверсия, значит результат будет обратный
2. `std::enable_if` - если условие правдиво, то тип будет тот, который указан вторым аргументом (в данном случае не указан - значит `void`), иначе члена вообще не будет существовать.

**Таким образом, если тип `callable` - арифметический, то функции не существует? Или что?**

И если можно, пару слов об этом:
`std::function<void()> task(std::bind(callable(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));`

Потому что я пока вообще не разобрался..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, если callable - арифметический тип, то произойдет ошибка подстановки аргументов шаблона. Т.е. это не будет ошибкой компиляции, и компилятор попытается найти другую реализацию setTimer. Ошибка компиляции, произойдет, только если не подойдет ни одна из перегрузок этой функции. Зачем эта проверка понадобилась автору - знает только автор. Возможно, есть еще одна версия setTimer, в которой 3-м аргументом должен быть обязательно арифметический тип? Логично выглядела бы проверка, что callable можно вызвать как функцию, с аргументами arguments: `std::is_invocable<callable, arguments...>`.

`std::bind` - рудимент пришедший из времен до c++11. Он позволяет связать функтор (т.е. функцию или объект с `operator()`) и некоторый набор аргументов, получив другой функтор, в котором в `operator()` , будет иметь меньше аргументов.  В C++11, для этих же целей обычно используются лямбда-выражения, которые более наглядны. Но move и forward говорят что это уже c++11.

Таким образом, выражение `std::bind(f, args...)` производит нечто, что имеет `operator()`, при вызове которого будет вызван  код `f(args...)`.

`std::forward` - это аналог move, применяемый для шаблонных типов, который позволяет передвигать аргументы, только если это позволено семантикой конкретных подставленных в шаблон типов. Почему автор написал `callable(f)` вместо `std::forward<callable>(f)` - знает только автор. Полагаю, это ошибка: объект f все время будет копироваться, даже если его можно перемещать. Хотя, авто явно знает о move и forward.

`std::function<void()>` -  универсальный контейнер в который можно положить что угодно, что имеет совместимый `operator()`. Т.е. в данном случае, оператор без аргументов, и возвращающий void. Это т.н. стирание типа. Мы расплачиваемся лишним вызовом виртуальной функции, при каждом вызове `std::function::operator()`, но получаем возможность сделать функцию, принимающею этот объект не шаблонной, а с аргументом конкретного типа. Вероятно, конструктор CTimer принимает именно его.

Comment: Очень Вас благодарю.